# What colour are the rings of Raggadorr?

Tags: marvel, comics, spells, doctor-strange

> Seven rings has Raggador
> Indigo to Deepest Black,
> but Oshtur grant me something more
> the Crimson bands of Cyttorak

What colour are the remaining five rings?

Comment: As can be seen from https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rings_of_Raggadorr/Gallery there is no consistency about what color the rings are—although they are usually portrayed as all being of the same color.

Comment: "*Although the Rings of Raggadorr are said to be shades of dark blue, they are frequently depicted as other colors such as red,[2][8][13][1] yellow,[12][14] or green.[13] However, this may be due to coloring errors.*" - https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rings_of_Raggadorr Note the multiplicity of examples given

Comment: these comments look like answers to me.

Comment: @Valorum, are you sure that does not mean that all the rings have the same color and there are 7 such colors possible?